# Oracle relative to which $\mathsf{BPP}$ is not contained in $Δ_2 \mathsf{P}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, relativization, polynomial-hierarchy, separation

[Complexity Zoology](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/relations.html#bpp) by Greg Kuperberg states that there is a language $X$ such that $\mathsf{BPP}^X \nsubseteq \mathsf{\Delta_2 \mathsf{P}}^X$ — in other words, $\mathsf{BPP}^X \nsubseteq \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}^X}$ — but does not give a reference for this result.  Why does this hold?  Or where can a proof be found?

This question is partly motivated by [my answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8297/what-is-known-about-multi-prover-interactive-proofs-with-short-messages/8429#8429) to the question “What is known about multi-prover interactive proofs with short messages?” by Joe Fitzsimons.

I posted this question on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69318/oracle-relative-to-which-bpp-is-not-contained-in-2p) on October 2, but I did not receive any answer and deleted the question on math following [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/what-is-the-proper-way-to-acknowledge-an-answer-posted-on-another-forum-site/1735#1735) on meta.math.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-92-078.pdf

Comment: @Alessandro: Thanks, it seems very relevant.  I will check it.

Comment: the link to the Complexity Zoo entry got lost in the editing of the answer. Here it is, updated after @MarcosVillagra request: http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:D#delta2p

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The oracle goes back to [Stockmeyer](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800061.808740) in 1983. [Heller](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958%2886%2980012-2) gave the stronger result that : $BPP = EXP^{NP}$ in a relativized world in 1986. [Karpiniski and Verbeek](http://www.springerlink.com/content/72u535t135323r2n/) (mentioned in the comments) reprove Heller's result.

Comment: Thank you for nailing it down.  I will wait for one day or two and then accept unless anything surprising happens.

Comment: it would be nice if someone updates the entry in the complexity zoo. I could do it, but I don't know how.

Comment: @MarcosVillagra maybe just email Greg Kuperberg ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat If you mean the Complexity Zoology, unfortunately that's not a public wiki. If you mean the Complexity Zoo, then I've already updated it.